# How do mobile apps store messages locally?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, socket.io, ionic-framework, mean-stack

For some reason this is very difficult to find, but I am trying to make a messaging app using the Ionic Framework and MEAN stack but was wondering...

1. What are the best practices to send and retrieve messages(socket.io or another node module) for a hybrid app?
2. How should an app store these messages(sqllite or nosql) using Ionic?
3. What **format** (Json?) should they be stored in for sorting and print retrieval on the chat screen?

Answers are much appreciated and **links** would be **really** help to further my own research.

Answer (score 0):

well if you are doing a mean stack then you will be using a mongo database (M: Mongo, E: express, A: angular, N: node). Socket Io will be the best method I know of to send messages. You will store them on the Mongo DB. Since you will be using mongo DB you will be using Json format I:E: {user: "", Message: "", MSGID: ""}.

Some Links:
https://github.com/DaftMonk/mean-chat
https://www.airpair.com/ionic-framework/posts/ionic-socketio-chat-application-tutorial
http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/demo-ionic-chat-app/13324

Comment: Do I have to store them in Mongo database? I should be able to use the server to send and recieve messages and store them on the phone

Comment: you do if you are using the mean stack. The only way I know to store them locally in a hybrid app is local storage which is not very safe for persistent storage. http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/localstorage/